# How Can I Run a RegExp Sub on Every gz in a Folder with Bash/Sed/Awk?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a bunch of gzipped files in a folder where each line of each file is of the form:

```
thing, thing2, something, thing4, other_thing, etc...
```

All I want to do is replace the first two commas in each line of each file with tabs, so that each line should look like:

```
thing\t thing2\t something, thing4, other_thing, etc...
```

There are a ton of these files, so I'm just looking for the fastest, most painless way of running this huge replacement. At the end, I'd like to have all of the same files with the same file names and just that one replacement. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ -d $1 ]] || exit 1
for gz in "$1"/*.gz ; do
    zcat "$gz" | sed 's/,/\t/;s/,/\t/' > "$gz".tmp
    gzip "$gz".tmp
    mv "$gz".tmp.gz "$gz"
done
```

Comment: Works, except sed is unreliable for "\t" replacing tabs on some OS' (i.e. OS X). More reliable is just using putting in a literal tab, or using awk in place of sed. Gets the job done for me though, so +1! Thanks!

Comment: I prefer `$'\t'` to literal tab in bash scripts. Whitespace can get changed by a text editor.

Comment: Make sure you add "&&" to the end of each line above that creates/updates a file or you'll end up zapping your original file if you can't write to a tmp one.

Comment: @EdMorton: Or just add `-e` to the shebang line.

Comment: That would probably work OK in this case but in general I wouldn't do it since it doesn't give you a chance to print specific error messages on individual command failures and it treats the failure of grep to find a string the same as the failure of ">" to create a file which is usually not what you want. It's best to just use "&&"s where you need them.

Comment: @EdMorton: With `-e`, you can still add `||` to lines that can fail :-)

Comment: :-) Obviously that would be negative logic and so is best avoided as it makes the code more complicated and creates double negatives. "doA && doB; doC;" is significantly easier to understand than "doA; doB || doC;".

Comment: My logic was wrong (told you it gets complicated!). With bash -e the logic to execute "doC" regardless of the succ/fail status from doB would need to be "doA; doB || doD; doC;" or "doA; doB && doD; doC;" where doD is a command that does nothing such as ":".

Comment: @EdMorton: Well, I use it a lot, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with GNU find and GNU parallel:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | parallel -0 \
  gzip -dc {} \| sed "s/,/$'\t'/; s/,/$'\t'/" \| gzip \> {}.tmp \; mv {}.tmp {}
```

Run parallel with `--dry-run` to see what will happen.